# How To write a SQL Select Query for this problem?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have four tables: groups, users, votes, follows.

The structures of these tables are

**groups**

```
g_id      g_title      g_content
 1          t1         content1   
 2          t2         content2
```

**users**

```
u_id      u_groupid
 1         1
 2         1
 3         2
 4         2
 5         2
```

**votes**

```
v_id      v_userid      v_groupid      v_votes
 1         1             1              1
 2         1             2              1
 3         2             2              1
 4         3             2              1
 5         3             1              1
```

**follows**

```
f_id      f_userid      f_groupid
 1         1             1
 2         2             1
 3         2             2
 4         3             1
 5         3             2
```

The groups table records the basic information of a "group".

The users table keeps the relationship between users and groups, that is, if the user A belongs to groups B, then there will be a record in the user table.

The votes table means the supportive attitude that a user holds to a group.

If user A is interested in group A, then add a entry into the Follows table.

Now my problem is how to write **one** select statement to query the number of users, the number of votes and the number of followers of each group.

I want the query result likes this

```
g_id      num_users      unm_votes      num_followers    
 1           2              2                3
 2           3              3                2
```

By the way, my database is Mysql 5.0.51b.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want in 1 query, something like this will help you

```
SELECT g_id, 
       d1.num_users, 
       d2.unm_votes, 
       d3.num_followers 
FROM   groups gg 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT g_id, 
                         COUNT(u.u_id) AS num_users 
                  FROM   groups g 
                         LEFT JOIN users u 
                           ON u.u_groupid = g.g_id 
                  GROUP  BY g_id) d1 
         ON d1.g_id = gg.g_id 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT g_id, 
                         COUNT(v.v_userid) AS unm_votes 
                  FROM   groups g 
                         LEFT JOIN votes v 
                           ON v.v_groupid = g.g_id 
                  GROUP  BY g_id) d2 
         ON d2.g_id = gg.g_id 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT g_id, 
                         COUNT(f.f_userid) AS num_followers 
                  FROM   groups g 
                         LEFT JOIN follows f 
                           ON f.f_groupid = g.g_id 
                  GROUP  BY g_id) d3 
         ON d3.g_id = gg.g_id 
GROUP  BY gg.g_id
```

Answer (score 0):

For the user count by group:

```
select g_id,count(u.uid) user_count  from groups g, users u 
where u.groupid = g.g_id
group by g_id
```

May want to read up on group by.